# How to select paths from a Monte Carlo Simulation that meet a specified condition (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy, simulation, montecarlo

I am using geometric Brownian motion to simulate the path of stock prices. However, I want to be able to set a boundary value and select and count the paths that lie above the boundary. There are a lot of posts about Monte Carlo Simulations on this forum. But I cannot find how to select individual paths.

My code for the simulation is below. The paths are stored in the variable `price_paths`. The red line in the image is an example of the boundary B that I want to set. So for example, how can I select the paths that are above the line and never touch it, store them in a separate list or dataframe and then count them and do other calculations on them?

[image: Select paths from a Monte Carlo Simulation that are above a boundary and never touch it]

```
import numpy as np
from math import log, e
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data

stock = 'AAPL' # Name of the stock
start = '2015/6/1'
T = 1 
B = 355
apple = data.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start)
spot = apple["Adj Close"][-1]

apple['log_price'] = np.log(apple['Adj Close'])
apple['log_return'] = apple['log_price'].diff()
mu = apple.log_return.sum()/apple.log_return.count()
mu = mu*365 + 0.5*apple.log_return.var()*np.sqrt(365)
sigma = np.std(apple.log_price)

s0 = apple["Adj Close"][-1]
delta_t = 1/365
num_reps = 10000
steps = T/delta_t
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
closing_prices = []
for j in range(num_reps):
    price_path = [s0] # The paths are stored here
    st = s0
    for i in range(int(steps)):
        drift = (mu - 0.5 * sigma**2) * delta_t
        diffusion = sigma * np.sqrt(delta_t) * np.random.normal(0, 1)
        st = st*e**(drift + diffusion)
        price_path.append(st)
        closing_prices.append(price_path[-1])
    plt.plot(price_path)
plt.ylabel('stock price',fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('steps',fontsize=15)
plt.axhline(y = B, color = 'r', linestyle = '-') # Line to indicate the barrier B
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks like element in price_path is a list of values in step. I think you can get the minimum value of each price_path and check if is > B or <=B.

Comment: Can you show my how to code this? No value along the path can touch or go below B. And I cannot figure out how to code that.

Comment: is st a list? or just a number?

Comment: Do you want `closing_prices` to contain every element of every price path? Currently, `closing_prices` is basically all of the price paths concatenated (merged) together. Did you actually want `closing_prices` to contain the last element from each price path?

Comment: @sam: st when initiated using s0 is a single number, it is the last and most recent stock price.

Comment: @ toothpick-anemone: ideally “closing_prices would contain every element of every path. So that I can find out when a path touches the boundary but also figure out the end price of every path. At the same time, I need to know how many paths stay above the boundary and/ or how many touch it.

Comment: @twhale `closing_prices` might be useful for something, but `closing_prices won't help you find when a path touches the boundary (horizontal line). `closing_prices` contains every element of every path, but we have no idea which path an element in `closing_prices` is copied from. For example, `closing_prices[561]` might be from path 20, might be from path 21; we have no idea. There is a difference between a list of lists and a list of numbers. `closing_prices` is a list of numbers. For example, how can you tell which elements of `closing_prices` are the last elements of each path?

Comment: @ Toothpick Anemone: Well, what I do to find at least the average of the last elements is this ```mean_end_price = round(np.mean(closing_prices),2)```

Comment: @ Toothpick Anemone: would it be possible to store the paths as a list of lists - rather than a list of numbers? If that helps.